# Functions of fractional-order Sobolev spaces

Tags: sobolev-spaces, finite-element-method

In fracture mechanics one might end up dealing with functions such as
$$w(r,\theta) = \sqrt{r} \sin \frac \theta 2,$$
which is defined, for example, on a cracked unit circle, $\Omega = B(0,1)\setminus\{(x,0)\,|\,-1\leq x < 0\}$, and where $(r,\theta)$ is the polar coordinate system originated at $(0,0)$ and oriented "in the standard fashion", i.e. $\theta=0$ corresponds to the positive $x$-axis.

It is quite often remarked in related mathematical literature that $w \in H^{3/2-\epsilon}(\Omega)$, $\forall \epsilon > 0$, and *this is something I'd like to show explicitly*. Here $H^s(\Omega)$, $s\in \mathbb{R}_+$, denotes the fractional-order Sobolev space $W^{s,2}(\Omega)$.

The unfortunate thing is that the fractional-order Sobolev space is often not defined rigorously in these texts and only a citation to *Adams - Sobolev Spaces* or to some similar classical text is done. Fortunately, I'm quite certain that the definition is either through the Fourier transform or through the Slobodeckij seminorm (cf. Wikipedia article *[Sobolev space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Sobolev_spaces_with_non-integer_k)*). The latter approach I've tried with unsatisfactory results. Such an approach involves evaluation of integrals of the form
$$\int_\Omega \int_\Omega \frac{|\partial_x w(\boldsymbol{x})-\partial_x w(\boldsymbol{y})|^2}{|\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y}|^3} \, \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{x}\,\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{y},$$
which, however, turned out to be a challenging task.

Is there any simple approach for showing that $w \in H^{3/2-\epsilon}(\Omega)$?

Comment: I'm a little late here, but there's a really nice proof that the fractional Sobolev norm defined using the Fourier transform is equivalent to the Slobodeckij norm in chapter 25 of Francois Treves's Basic Linear Partial Differential Equations.